# Hidden textField cant be selected after isHidden set to false

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Firstly, i have no storyboards and everything is programmatic. I have three TextFields, one of which is hidden(isHidden = true) behind a login button, below the login button is a register button. If you tap the register button the login button slides down below the register button then the hidden textField has its isHidden property set to false.

My issue at the moment is that when tapping the register button the login button moves down and the textfield displays but cant be selected and when i do try to select it the login button snaps back to its original position.

I also have the view moving up when the keyboard is displayed and down again and i dont think this is helping.

TextField:

```
class SplitterTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var accessID: String!

    required init(frame: CGRect, accessID: String) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.accessID = accessID
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func setup() {
        delegate = self
        backgroundColor = Color.textFieldBackground
        accessibilityIdentifier = accessID
        textAlignment = .center
        returnKeyType = .done
        placeholder = NSLocalizedString("\(accessID!)PlaceHolder", comment: "")
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

move button functions:

```
@objc private func registerButtonTapped() {
    if confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden {
        animateLoginButton()
    } else {
        registerNewUser()
    }
}


@objc private func loginButtonTapped() {
    if !confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden {
        animateLoginButton()
    } else {
        //segue to next vc
    }
}

private func animateLoginButton() {
    if confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden {
        moveLoginButtonDown()
    } else {
        moveLoginButtonUp()
    }
}

private func moveLoginButtonDown() {
    //Move loginButton down revealing confirmationPasswordTextView behind it
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.loginButton.frame.origin.y += Layout.loginButtonYMovement
        self.confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden = false
    })
}

private func moveLoginButtonUp() {
    //Move the loginButton up, when it has finished moving hide the confirmationPasswordTextView
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.loginButton.frame.origin.y -= Layout.loginButtonYMovement
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden = true
    })
}
```

view controller keyboard functions:

```
func setupKeyboard() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(sender:)),name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,object: nil)

}

@objc private func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y = Layout.welcomeScreenKeyboardMovement
}

@objc private func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks, let me know if there is more context needed. All views are pinned using constraints and no errors occur involving constraints.

Comment: when pressing register button add this line of code. 
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: confirmPasswordTextField) then try to select that field.

Comment: Amazing thanks! The textField works but adding that now makes the login button jump up it was and slide down behind the newly revealed textfield. any ideas?

Comment: @WyneRumble You have to do the same with all fields when pressing register button. also have to set the frames of button accordingly so that they don't mess with eachother.

Comment: I am posting it as an answer. please accept it. Thanks

Comment: Did You solve the issue of login button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when pressing register button add this line of code.

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: confirmPasswordTextField)
```

then try to select that field.
Set the frames buttons properly so that they don't mess with each other.
You can print the button frames for better understanding.

Comment: Most Welcome :)